# XPages form in A4 format

Tags: printing, xpages

I would like to create a XPages form to print it out. I am not sure which is the best way to do this. I mean I need to create a panel or table or any other design elements then put all my staff in it?

I need advise:)
Regards
Cumhur Ata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speak after me: browsers don't print.

If you need precision layout a browser is your worst enemy. Each one renders slightly different, so don't bother.

Your best bet is to create a PDF file for printing. There you have pixel-perfect rendering as you deem fit.

You can use iText, PDFBox or XSL:FO to generate PDF. There are code samples on OpenNTF or you read [my blog entries](http://www.notessensei.com/blog/2012/04/extracting-data-from-domino-into-pdf-using-xslt-and-xslfo-part-1.html) about it.

Comment: I totally agree with Stephan. Go the PDF way and let the user print it. POI4XPages is a easy to use project on OpenNTF. I use it all the time, it fits for most of the use cases. When not go for the vanilla Apache POI or other Open source PDF generators.

Comment: There's been several shows on NotesIn9 regarding creating PDF's from XPages.  That might be a good start.  #39, #62 and #102 I think might be helpful.  That being said at the day job we use iText which is nice, but it's not free.